# Outsourced Partner or Outsourcing partner?

Tags: past-participles, present-participles

I'm not an English native speaker. My lecturer in my university keeps using "outsourced partner" instead of "outsourcing partner", while I saw everyone in internet is more often using "outsourcing partner".

I can differentiate the difference between "outsourced" and "outsourcing" (Do correct me if I'm wrong):

A. The product is outsourced. (The product has been outsourced to the third party, adjective and passive form).
B. The company is outsourcing the product. (The company outsources the product in present continuous form).

However, I'm confused on the usage of "outsourced partner" and "outsourcing partner". May I know if there's any difference between them? Or do both have the same meaning?

Examples: Result of searching "outsourcing partner", and my lecture note.

[image]
[image]
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide examples of sentences containing "outsourced partner" and "outsourcing partner".

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks for your help. I've just added examples.

Comment: You're welcome. From those examples, it looks like *outsourcing* is used as a gerund to qualify *partner* (like ***baking** tray*), while *outsourced* is used as an adjective to describe the partner (like ***baked** treats*).

Comment: On closer inspection, *outsourcing partner* is used in that example to refer to themselves as the ones who do the work. This is less like *baking tray* and more like *a bottle of **rubbing** alcohol*. The -ing word acts like an adjective. So both forms (-ing, -ed) function similarly in their respective contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Outsourcing Partner* is someone who is doing the outsourcing. Present tense.

*Outsourced Partner* is someone who was outsourced. Past tense.

Answer (score 0):

The term *outsourced* partner *could* indicate that it/they were once part of the organisation, as in a team from a university research group that leave in order to commercialise the results of some successful research.

Comment: From the details you posted it seems you’re quite right, and for the reasons you gave.

*outsourcing partner* is rather unusual, but quite correct.

*outsourced partner* sounds like an impossibility; at best, a contradiction in terms. How could that be different from an *outsourced husband/wife/spouse*? For broadly the same reason, past tense doesn’t change the relationship; nor does the group leaving the university.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is past and present tense.

Outsourced Partner is past tense, could be used in present tense.

Outsourcing Partner is present tense and wouldn't be used in past tense.